# href syntax // or http:// ?

Tags: html, hyperlink

What are the differencies between this syntax

```
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and this one

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

is there some issue with compatibility on some web browser ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference.

Using only `//` will cause the external element to be pulled in using the same protocol as the initial request. For example, if you use:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And then access `https://www.example.com/`, FontAwesome will be pulled in using `https`. If you access: `http://www.example.com/`, it'll be fetched using `http`.

Your second example explicitly sets the protocol for the request (in this case, `http`).

For future reference, it's always best to pull in CDN resources via HTTPS.

Comment: And what if the user come to my website using http and the ressource is only on a https server ?